# how can i make the input work with my parameters?

Tags: function, parameters, python-3.6

I have started a python class and my book does not seem to help me.
My professor has a program that bombards my code with different inputs and if any of the inputs do not work then my code is "wrong". I have done many days worth of editing and am at a complete loss. I have the code working if someone puts and input of an actual number. But where my code fails the test is if input is "miles_to_laps(26)" it errors out.

I have tried changing the input to int(input()) but that does not fix the issue. I've gone through changing variables and even changing the input method but still am at a loss. I have already tried contacting my teacher but 6 days of no response and 3 days of being late i feel like I'm just going no where.

```
user_miles = int(input())

def miles_to_laps(user_miles):
    x = user_miles
    y = 4
    x2 = x * y
    result = print('%0.2f' % float(x2))
    return result

miles_to_laps(user_miles)
```

my code works for real number inputs but my professor is wanting inputs like 
miles_to_laps(26) and miles_to_laps(13) to create the same outputs.

Comment: based on your code, why would miles_to_laps(26) and miles_to_laps(13) return same values? you seem to calculate 26 * 4 and 13 * 4. Did you mean division?

Comment: i did the multiplication because / .25 was not giving the same values but she is wanting me to call the def function using miles_to_laps(13) to give the same output if the input was just 13

Comment: You can check if the input is a number, and if it is not, then try to `eval` / `exec` the input, excepting `(NameError, TypeError)`, which should cause the program to output `Invalid Input` (You need to implement this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the wierd input functionality you can try:

```
import re

def parse_function_text(s):
    try:
        return re.search("miles_to_laps\((.+)\)", s)[1]
    except TypeError:
        return None

def accept_input(user_input):
    desugar = parse_function_text(user_input)
    if desugar is not None:
        user_input = desugar    
    try:
        return float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Cannot process input %s" % user_input)

assert accept_input("miles_to_laps(3.5)") == 3.5
```

Comment: could you explain this to me a bit? alot in there just went WAY over my head also when i try to run your code to test it with inputs it says 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    assert accept_input("miles_to_laps(3.5)") == 3.5
  File "main.py", line 8, in accept_input
    desugar = parse_function_text(user_input)
  File "main.py", line 3, in parse_function_text
    return re.search("miles_to_laps\((.+)\)", s)[1]
NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: also want to say thank you for trying to help me figure this out its been an absolute headache for days now I really do appreciate it

Comment: You try catch what is inside () with regular expression, if there is something there, consider it numeric input and try to coerce to float type. Go over docs of `re` module to familiarise with regex.

Comment: Put `import re` at top

Comment: also assert is like a check, just a demo of how function works

Comment: awesome! so after import re at the top then basically what i am understanding is that the code you put there would take the numeric input from the input "miles_to_laps(3.5)" and register it as an input of 3.5 which would allow me to use that input inside my code to get the answer?

Comment: More or less so. ) there can be varieties on what to consider a numeric inside parenthesis, but for base case you have it. Feel free to mark as accepted answer if it suits.

Comment: Hope you get a more meaningful assignment next time. )

Comment: only thing that im running into now is that it is saying it cannot convert the string to an integer

Comment: Make it a separate question with minimal code example, need to see your input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829460/revised-to-earlier-question-program-laps-to-miles

link to new question

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to keep all the pedantism aside, but what kind of CS/programming teaching is that?

Areas of concern:

- separate user input from rest of code
- separate output formatting from function output
- the code inside miles_to_laps is excessive

Now here is the code  to try:

```
LAPS_PER_MILE = 4

# the only calculation, "pure" function    
def miles_to_laps(miles):
    return LAPS_PER_MILE * miles

# sorting out valid vs invalid input, "interface"
def accept_input(user_input):
    try:
        return float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Cannot process input %s" % user_input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # running the program
    laps = miles_to_laps(accept_input(input()))
    print ('%0.2f' % laps)
```

Hope this is not too overwhelming.

Update: second attempt

```
MILE = 1609.34 # meters per mile
LAP = 400      # track lap
LAPS_PER_MILE = MILE/LAP

def miles_to_laps(miles):
    return LAPS_PER_MILE * miles

def laps_coerced(laps):
    return '%0.2f' % laps

def accept_input(user_input):
    try:
        return float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Cannot process input %s" % user_input)

def main(user_input_str):
    miles = accept_input(user_input_str)
    laps = miles_to_laps(miles)
    print (laps_coerced(laps))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(input())
```

Comment: so this the code does the same output as my original post but it doesn't allow for input to be "miles_to_laps(30)" which is what my professor requires. this is where I'm at a loss

Comment: Like literally typing in miles_to_laps(30) as an input string? So that input accepts both 30 and miles_to_laps(30)? That is fairly strange thing to ask.

Comment: Yes literally typing in miles_to_laps(30) I agree this is EXTREMELY strange thing to ask for an input but thats the requirement for her answer Its also the only reason im stuck

Comment: see one on the options in a separate answer