# revised to earlier question: program laps to miles

Tags: python, function

```
import re

user_miles = input()

def miles_to_laps(user_miles):
miles = float(user_miles) * 4
    print('%0.2f'% miles)
    return
miles_to_laps(user_miles)

def parse_function_text(s):
    try:
        return re.search("miles_to_laps\((.+)\)", s)[1]
    except TypeError:
        return None

def accept_input(user_input):
    desugar = parse_function_text(user_input)
    if desugar is not None:
        user_input = desugar    
    try:
        return float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Cannot process input %s" % user_input)

assert accept_input("miles_to_laps(3.5)") == 3.5
```

So doing this to show the new code that is being used to create the program allowing for the input to be " miles_to_laps(20)"
my error code for this right now is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    miles_to_laps(user_miles)
  File "main.py", line 6, in miles_to_laps
    miles = float(user_miles) * 4
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'miles_to_laps(20)'
```

Comment: have you tried removing the `assert` statement, also indentation on line 6

Comment: thank you ill give that a shot and let you know

Comment: okay so i tried that out and still gives me the same error

Comment: works fine for me, https://trinket.io/python/3869823d76

Comment: i dont get why its not working but my submission is erroring out like crazy

Comment: First you assign user input `input()` to `user_miles` on line 3. Then, on line 9, you pass that into the function `miles_to_laps` where you cast `user_miles` into a float on line 6 - that's still a string (as input by the user), so that causes the error. The rest of the code is never reached.

Comment: but if input is "miles_to_laps(30)" it can not be changed to a integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code accepts an input, but always returns a string, so if you type a `20` as a response to this input, it is stored in memory as a `'20'` (a string OR `str` type)

```
user_miles = input()
```

Your function is intended to perform math and thus expects numbers (i.e. integer type (`int`) OR a float type (`float`).

The easiest way to fix this is to immediately convert the string to an integer, using the `int()` function to wrap the `input()` function.

```
user_miles = int(input())
```

Comment: your missing the input requirement from my professor. The input MUST contain "miles_to_laps(9)" as an input. The string cannot be converted to an integer from user input if the string contains non numeric characters. This is why I'm getting so stressed out. 
'''python
    user_miles = int(input()) 
'''
returns:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'miles_to_laps(8)'

Comment: @MicahSchenk is there a possibility that there is a misunderstanding betwixt you and the professor with regards to the assert statement? It is common to feed one function, such as the `miles_to_laps()` function into another function, but it is not common in Python to feed a string of a function name i.e. encapsulating the function name with quotes as the input to another function. Consider the difference between: 

`assert accept_input("miles_to_laps(x)") == x.x` VERSUS `assert accept_input(miles_to_laps(x)) == x.x`

Comment: i actually have resolved the issue it was very much so a communication issue my professor was telling us that the input was going to be multiple different integer values and also a input of miles_to_laps(30) well I have since found out that the issue is that there wasnt an input of miles_to_laps(30) it was a injection to my script which made it MUCH less complex! thank you all for your help in resolving the issue prior!